# Dblookupcombobox listfieldindex Setando o index o combobox vem vazio

Tags: sql, delphi

Estou com um problema com o Dblookupcombobox, mesmo setando o valor do listfieldindex , ele não está trazendo o item para o combobox

```
cbcPais.ListIndex := 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma Usando keyValue

```
cbcPais.keyValue :=1;
```